# Is there a way to get a feedback from the Firebase extension "Resize Images" once it is completed? - Flutter Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage, firebase-extensions

I'm facing the following issue:

1. I upload an Image to Firebase Storage

```
//Start the upload
await StorageHandler.instance.uploadTask(mediaIDPath, largeFile);
```

2. Once the upload is completed, the Firebase Extension "Resize Image" will be triggered.
   The Resized Imaged will be stored separately in **another** path in my FirebaseStorage
3. In order to make sure that the image is resized I'm waiting 4 seconds in my code (which is not the right way how to solve this problem)

```
//Start the upload
await StorageHandler.instance.uploadTask(mediaIDPath, largeFile);

//After the upload is completed, wait 4 seconds until the image is resized
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));
```

4. Then I'm fetching the URL of the resized Image.
   I need the download URL immediately in order to display image in a GridView as soon as the image is resized and added to the ***other*** path which I've mentioned in point 2.

```
//Start the upload
await StorageHandler.instance.uploadTask(mediaIDPath, largeFile);

//After the upload is completed, wait 4 seconds until the image is resized
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 4));

//fetch the imageURL of the resized Image
gridURL = await StorageHandler.instance.getImageURLFromStorage(mediaIDPathResizedFile);
```

To wait 4 seconds is not the right way. Therefore I'm seeking for a possibility to get a feedback from the Storage that the Resize is completed that I can fetch the download URL afterwards.
I couldn't find any method in Firebase which provides this functionality.

Important note: I don't want to resize the image on client side to avoid more upload operations and keep the firebase costs at the minimum!

Does anyone have an idea for a workaround to avoid waiting 4 seconds in my case?

I hope I explained my problem clear enough and looking forward for helpful suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built into the resize images extension to signal completion to the calling client.

The typical way to implement this yourself would be to create a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions) that [triggers when a file being written to Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events), and if the file is a thumbnail to implement the send a signal to the calling client (for example, by storing information in the [metadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#add_file_metadata) of the file on how to reach the client) through something like FCM, or one of Firebase's databases (Realtime Database, or Cloud Firestore).

Comment: Thanks for you answer Frank. I think this would be best approach but I'm not that familiar writing cloud functions since I'm quite a beginner. Could you suggest some best practice websites where I can learn everything that is needed to write Cloud functions? 

Thanks

Comment: I included links to the relevant documentation in my answer, which is a great place to start. If you're more into doing than reading, the [codelab for Cloud Functions](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/) might also be helpful.

Comment: This is quite convoluted compared to say writing an http request and waiting for a response. Which is what we have opted to do instead: an https function that handle file uploads.